# handle sharp after query string in asp.net mvc

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

i'm using facebook application using Facebook sharp. When i send permission request to facebook, Facebook send to me this url
`mywebsite.com/facebook/gettoken#access_token=CODE&Expired_in=1232`

```
public ActionResult gettoken(string access_token){
...
}
```

`access_token` return `null`

I'm checking `Request.Url`. but don't have any `access_token` parameter

How to get access_token in asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your redirect_uri you have a #. Take it out.

A # is a client side tag to say everything after this is for client browsers only and is never passed to the server, hence you never receive the access_token.

**Additional Note**

You can see the hash in Javascript as it is client side. Incase you decide to use the JS Facebook SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Change the # in a ?. The first parameter should be an ?